# Add Github token to android studio permanently

Tags: android-studio, github

I have already configured my Android studio with my git-Hub Account in Version Control with Token.
problem statement is --
I am trying to add,commit,push my android project from android studio's terminal
but when i try to do that on every commit it asks for token, is there any way to add the git hub token to set it permanently so that if i commit again the terminal should not ask for token again..

I have already configured my Android studio with my git-Hub Account in Version Control with Token.
I have already generated a token for the particular project.

Answer (score 2):

It would be annoying if there wasn't a way to do it ;)

If you already got your token (from: https://github.com/settings/tokens),
you may go to:

File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub

[image]

Then just press the '+' sign and choose 'Log in with Token'

[image: Result]

Then you just paste the token in here and your next push should go smoothly